# When does toCharArray get called at runtime

Tags: java

In the following code, I know that string concat is done at compile time, but toCharArray is done at runtime. My question - When during runtime does toCharArray get executed ? Is it before the constructor is executed, similar to static blocks ?

```
private final static char[] DigitTens = {
     ("0000000000"+ "1111111111"+"2222222222"+"3333333333"+"4444444444" //
     +"5555555555"+"6666666666"+"7777777777"+"8888888888"+"9999999999")
      .toCharArray();             
};
```

Comment: It _is_ a `static` block. Not that `static` blocks are **not** executed _before the constructor is executed_; they are executed at class initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static initializers are executed in the order they are defined (top down, just like simple variable initializers) when the class is loaded. On this this case toCharArray() will get initialize when the Class gets initialize.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a static initialization.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) `toCharArray()` will get called when the class is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

When the class that contains DigitTens gets called.